# Read state from React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code

```
const initialState = {
    values: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    },
    touched: {
        email: false,
        password: false
    },
    errors: false,
    isValid: false,
    isLoading: false,
    submitError: null
};

function SignIn(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state);
    });

    const handleFieldChange = (field, value) => {
        const newState = state;

        newState.submitError = null;
        newState.touched[field] = true;
        newState.values[field] = value;

        newState.errors = true; // set to true just for test

        setState(newState);

    };

    const showEmailError = state.errors.email;


    return (
        <div>
        <TextField
            className={classes.textField}
            label="Email address"
            name="email"
            onChange={event => handleFieldChange('email', event.target.value)}
            type="text"
            value={state.email}
            variant="outlined"

        />

        {showEmailError && (
            <Typography
                className={classes.fieldError}
                variant="body2"
            >
                {state.errors.email[0]}
            </Typography>
        )}
        </div>
    )
    }
```

The problem that I have is that when the `handFieldChange` is executed, the email error does not appear. It's like I don't get the latest state change in my return statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI doing `const newState = state;` and then using `newState`, you're still working with your old state object

Comment: Yes, I know. But that's not the problem here.

Comment: that is exactly the problem @Bryan

Comment: Just a heads up, you `useEffect` serves no purpose here, just doing `console.log(state);` will show you your state changes.   Once you have fixed your state changes of course.. :)

Comment: @Keith: Yeah I know. I was adding that for testing purpose to see if the component was re-rendered, but since I worked with the same object, It was not :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave you a hint in comments but it seems like you ignored it. You should not mutate the state object directly as when you call setState, React compares it with your original state object reference (thanks for Ross to point it out in comments). Since you've already mutated it anyway and React doesn't find any changed properties, your component is not updated and hence `useEffect` hook is not called. Create a new reference to your state object before working. Here's what you need to do:

Replace

```
const newState = state;
```

with

```
const newState = { ...state }
```

Comment: @mehuimpt: Oh, sorry. Yes ofc! I was translating https://github.com/devias-io/react-material-dashboard/blob/master/src/views/SignIn/index.jsx from class components to hooks, and missed this.... Thank you.!

Comment: Should mention that `destructuring` is not a deep clone and may lead to unexpected behavior. Also when performance considered, should try and use own/library deep clone function like lodash `_.deepClone`.

Comment: @DennisVash I meant recursive destructuring there. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @mehulmpt: So I should avoid to destruct like this: { ...state }?

Comment: { ...state } is fine if you have stuff to change only at a single level (like state.prop1 or state.prop2), if you want to change `state.prop1.nestedprop1` then you have to do something like `const newstate = { ...state, prop1: { ...state.prop1 } }` to shallow clone the `state.prop1`, or you can just stringify and parse it as JSON again as soon as it is JSON friendly (i.e. no functions or circular dependencies, in most cases you don't need to worry about that in a state object) @Bryan

Comment: `useState` uses Object identity by default, so if `newState` is a new Object then `useState` will return that new Object. You don't need a deep clone to make this work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to store big object, like in this case, use `useReducer` instead of `useState`.

By typing `const newState = state;` you're assigning same object, so you'll work with still same object. Use `const newState = {...state}` or sth like that.

Lets' look below:

```
const showEmailError = state.errors.email;
[...]
{state.errors.email[0]}
```

Your state.errors property is boolean, so it doesn't have any nested objects.

---

In useEffect, you need to pass dependencies array, which will be tracked and call function on any change. To call it only once, pass empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
}, []);
```

If u want to log every state changes, pass state as a dependency.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to remove that. When I replace state.errors.email with just random text, nothing appears.

Comment: The problem I have is that the useEffect is only logged once, even though I don't pass any arguments to it.

Comment: Yes, if you want to log every state changes, you need to pass state as a dependency to useEffect - then will be logged every change.

Answer (score -1):

`setState` thinks that nothing is changing because you're passing it the same `state` Object every time. Create a new Object on each update:

```js
const newState = { ...state };
```

Comment: this just might work but the moment the OP removes `error = true` from the callback, shallow cloning (and hence this method) would fail because your code is still working the property of the same object. Destructuring like this creates a shallow clone.

Comment: `useState` uses the Object reference to determine whether to re-render. Why would you need a deep clone?

Comment: because in the question OP modifies nested properties `(obj.prop1.prop2...)` which are not cloned when you do a shallow clone like that

Comment: `useState` is only concerned with the Object passed to it, and if that reference changes then it will return an updated value. In the OP's case, the whole component will re-render and pick up the changes to nested Objects. There's no need for a deep clone here.